# What is ' in English reading

Tags: reading

What does ' mean in English reading and How to pronounce it and when to put it 
For example: ba'sabim(made up word)

Comment: Yes the apostrophe

Comment: You might be interested in the [Lexico punctuation guide](https://www.lexico.com/grammar/punctuation) and in particular their [apostrophe page](https://www.lexico.com/grammar/apostrophe).

Comment: I don't mean how to use it in English, like a pronoun, etc.  I mean I've seen a lot of people writing it as part of the example pronunciation of someone's last name.

Comment: Are looking for information on [**stress marks**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stress-mark) used to show pronunciation?

Comment: Sorry everyone I can't express, English is not my native language, I don't mean a 's like mikel's car .  I mean pronunciation.  For example, a friend of mine wrote my last name in this way sh'ahr why he added 'and I saw many more add'

Comment: Example: SH'AHR, Why did he add ', and how do you pronounce it and when you neet to add?

Comment: You don't pronounce it: please see the explanation in the link I posted.

Comment: But this artical does not answer my question

Comment: The stress mark is not pronounced. It is placed (in writing) next to the syllable that receives the most stress. So the stress mark in ba'sabim shows that it is pronounced ba**SAB**im, but it isn't actually part of the word. It's like underlining something.

Comment: Please don't use made up words. How can we tell you how to pronounce a made up word? Find a real word that includes an apostrophe and use that as your example.

Answer (score 2):

The apostrophe has 3 main uses in English grammar:

1) to form possessive nouns (eg "John's car")
2) to show the omission of letters (eg "Isn't" instead of "is not")
3) to indicate plurals of letters, numbers, and symbols (eg "dot the i's")

However, your example of a "made up word" is a little different:

> ba'sabim

Sometimes apostrophes are used as *pronunciation guides* to show that the syllable that follows is to be stressed or to break up syllables. This is normally used in English texts to show the pronunciation of *non-English nouns*. For example, the name *Jacob* is normally pronounced as two syllables in English; however, the original Hebrew name from which this is derived should be pronounced as *three* syllables. Rendering this as *ya'akov* breaks up two vowels that an English speaker would normally run together.

Similarly, with your example "basabim", the natural English pronunciation would probably be "bass-a-bim", but with the apostrophe included "ba'sabim" it would be "ba-sar-bim".

Comment: Besides thinking the question should be improved or deleted, in English we have: O'Donald, O'Shaughnessy etc. for Irish names.

Comment: @Lambie that would be included in point 2 - as historically those names are "Of Donald" etc